# [Ros2] Creating Multiple nodes using class inheritance

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering if you had an example on how to create multiple Nodes using the class inheritance.

In ros, I created multiple nodes using `ros::NodeHandle;`.

I read in one of the ros2 answers that I could use the following instead:

```
auto node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("...", ...);
node->create_publisher<...>("~/chatter", ...);
```

[link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/294483/private-nodehandles-in-ros-2/)

but in the publisher not_composable.cpp example which uses this method, it is written that:

> We do not recommend this style anymore, because composition of multiple
> nodes in the same executable is not possible. Please see one of the subclass

So, I guessed there was a better way to create multiple nodes using the inheritance class.

My current problem is that the Node is being created on the constructor of the inheritance class:

```
class MinimalPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalPublisher()
  : Node("minimal_publisher"), count_(0)
```

but, in my code I am not sure which publishers will be needed so, I want to be able to control when a Node is made.

---

Update to my question:

Basically, my question was brought out by a lack of understanding of how ros worked.
Trying to migrate to ros2 without fully understand ros first, was really dumb of me.

Thanks to the following post and its references I was able to learn more about ros and ros2:
[link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/287470/what-is-the-difference-between-ros-and-ros2/)

I initially thought that a publisher and a subscriber needed their own nodes which is entirely wrong.
What I meant by "I want to be able to control when a Node is made. " was basically me thinking that when a new publisher is created, a node needed to be initialized as well. I will keep on studying and before I make my next question I will do more thorough research.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313608/%5Bros2%5D-creating-multiple-nodes-using-class-inheritance/) by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The second example you provided is the correct way to go in ROS2.

I'm not sure about what do you mean with

> I want to be able to control when a Node is made

However you can easily replicate the same behavior of the first example also using the second, more correct, structure.

```
class MinimalPublisher : public rclcpp::Node {

public:
    
    MinimalPublisher() : Node("minimal_publisher")
    {
         RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Node created!!");
    } 

    void add_publisher()
    {
        _publisher = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("my_topic");
    }

private:

    rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr _publisher;

}
```

Then, just create an object of type `MinimalPublisher` when you need it and call the `add_publisher` method when you want to create the publisher.
Similarly you will have a method for publishing messages or you may want to set a `rclcpp::Timer`

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-01-25**:
I just wanted to thank you for responding to my question. I am sure it was hard to understand what exactly I wanted to ask.  I will learn from my mistake and read the documentation more carefully from now on.